# Are there CSRF attacks that don't use cookies?

Tags: http, csrf

Suppose an HTTP-server reads virtually no data from cookies at all. All data comes from different parts of request: headers, body, url, etc. Does this fact guarantee there can be no CSRF-attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF does not need cookies specifically. It needs authentication that is sent by a browser automatically. Other such forms of authentication include http basic auth and client certificates for example.

If a specific http header is used for authorization (eg. a bearer token), *that* effectively prevents CSRF.